# Data in field_revision with Create new revision unchecked

Tags: 7, nodes

The field_data_myfield and field_revision_myfield have the same row entries (D7 fields). All of my content types have the "Create new revision" unchecked. Is this how it's suppose to work? If yes, two questions 1) is this okay for scalability and 2) how do I stop drupal from renaming the files with _0 even when the original is deleted -- I read that this is because revision is on. If it's not suppose to work this way, how do I fix it.

I'm using mysql.

To clarify the end goal, I don't want the entire field deleted, I would like the fields not to track data revisions. Currently if field_body is updated, it also tracks it in field_revision body. Ideally, drupal would only save the update in field_body, and field_revision_body would be left empty. The content type is marked to not track revisions.

Comment: Even with revisions turned on, if you delete a file that is not used on any other revision the file will be removed. Since you are not using revisions there will be only one revision, which means when you delete a file the file should be deleted from the server and you should avoid the numeric suffixes on the file names.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this how it's suppose to work?**

It depends on which storage backend you use. The default sql backend works this way.

1. It shouldn't effect speed (much) but will instead effect data storage which usually isn't a problem.
2. Drupal will not completely delete a field, but instead mark it as deleted. If you want to completely delete it, you need to delete it from the `field_config` and `field_config_instance` tables.

Comment: Hello Googletorp, would it be safe to trunace the revision field? It does not seem it is used at all since revisioning is turned off.

Comment: @googletorp see also the http://drupal.org/project/field_sql_norevisions module ... its an all or nothing module that disables revision tables for your content types.