# How to disable the revision feature completely?

Tags: 7, nodes

I've followed discussions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/7-is-it-safe-to-truncate-a-field-revision-table) and on [d.o](http://drupal.org/node/1279440) about removing unneeded revisions tables.

How would I completely prevent any data from being written to the node_revision and field_revision_* tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Field SQL norevisions](https://drupal.org/project/field_sql_norevisions) actually solves exactly that problem by

> Field SQL norevisions provides a field storage backend using SQL that does not create a revision table for each field.

I haven't tried it, but anything written by Alex Pott can probably be expected to work properly.

I assume however that this also goes for *all* entites as it changes the storage backend.

Without a new storage engine, the below is the original, less useful, answer:

The revision tables *must* be available, and they *must* contain data. 
Unfortunately, you just *cannot* get rid of them without completely breaking Field API, the reason being that the revision, contrary to their name, is *the* data storage.

Perhaps it's possible, with more database wizardry than I know, that you can set the regular field_data_* tables to be mirrors of each revision table. That *might* work.

Other than that, I can't think of any solution that would do this.

**Edit:** While I don't know if this will have, "interesting", side effects, I asked the wizards if this was at all doable. [Can I have one table be an alias or symlink to another?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18425/can-i-have-one-table-be-an-alias-or-symlink-to-another).

**Edit 2:** Actually, it seems like much wizardry isn't needed at all. One could try replacing the field_data_* tables with a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html) that replicates the corresponding revision tables. Again, I haven't *tried* this, and my understanding of the interals of field api are a bit lacking, but it certainly *could* work.

**Edit 3:** (Yes, this is getting silly), someone pointed out that the above will cause the same data to be written twice, now to the *same* table. So it probably wont work anyway.

Comment: my understanding is that the node data is copied to the revision table (duplicated) and same for the field_data. If you could prevent the data from being inserted into those tables nothing should happen as long as you are not using the revision feature. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that it's the other way around. The revision tables are by core considered the canonical source of information. Field data, despite their name, are just denormalization.

Comment: that's interesting, thanks! Still a huge waste of resources for probably 90% of sites that don't use revisions.

Comment: Not true anymore! [Field SQL norevisions](http://drupal.org/project/field_sql_norevisions) claims to solve that problem. I haven't tried it but the code looks very promising! @MotoTribe found this one I can't take the credit ;)

Comment: Interesting that the module appears to have been written already when we had the initial discussion. @Clive, you should post that as a new answer. :)