# May I know the difference between field_data_body and field_revision_body?

Tags: views

As I am a beginner of this Drupal 7 I have some doubts regarding these database tables.I need  a short notes regarding all these database tables.The doubt which I had found is that when I add the content in Drupal 7 it is inserting in these two database tables i,e field_data_body and field_revision_body and in similar way when I add comment it is also doing the same functionality. I need someone's help.

Answer (score 5):

**In short:**

field_data_body is the current body data.

field_revision_body is a historic backup, that you can revert to if necessary.

**Detailed explanation of revision:**

> Drupal lets you create a new revision every time a node is updated.
>   This allows you to track how the node has changed over time on your
>   site.
>
> To enable this feature you go to the default node editing form (D6:
>   administer/content management/content types/edit/workflow settings;
>   D7: administer/structure/content types/edit/publishing options) and
>   check the box Create a new revision in the node editing form. This
>   will result in a new revision being created every time the node is
>   edited. (Administrators can override this when editing an individual
>   node.)
>
> To view and manage revisions, use the Revisions tab when viewing a
>   node (you must have "view revisions" or "administer nodes" permission
>   to view revisions.) From the Revisions tab, you can view the
>   individual revisions, revert to an earlier revision, and delete
>   revisions (you must have the "administer nodes" or "revert revisions"
>   and "delete revisions" permissions).
>
> One interesting detail of the system is the behaviour of the reverting
>   mechanism. Let's say you have revisions {1,2,3,current}. If you revert
>   to revision #2, a copy of #2 is made and the copy is set as the
>   current revision. Thus, after reverting you'll have {1,2,3,4,current},
>   where current is a clone of #2, and #4 is the previous current
>   revision.
>
> Another useful feature of the revision system is the Log field, which
>   appears near the "Create a new revision" check box on the node editing
>   form. If you add a message to the Log field when you create a
>   revision, that message will appear on the Revisions tab along with the
>   revision. It is a good idea to add a meaningful Log message whenever
>   you create a node revision, so that others (or you, months later) can
>   see why you changed the node and what your changes were, without
>   having to actually view the previous revision.
>
> You can enhance the revisions tab by installing the contributed [Diff
>   module](http://drupal.org/project/diff). This module allows you to see the differences between two
>   revisions; without this module, you can only view the entire content
>   of each revision, and it may be difficult to tell exactly what has
>   changed between the revisions.
>
> Note that the node_revisions table in the database will always have
>   one record associated with each record in the node table, which it
>   keeps track of as the current revision. This will happen even if you
>   do not have revisions enabled. On the other hand, if you have enabled
>   revisioning, you will have multiple entries in your node_revision
>   table associated with each node, corresponding, not just to the
>   current revision, but all past revisions too.

<sub>Source: [Node revisions](https://www.drupal.org/node/320614)</sub>

Related:

- [How to disable the revision feature completely?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32287/how-to-disable-the-revision-feature-completely)
- [Node Revision Cleanup](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_cleanup)